# group by and aggregate by join

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I want to produce a count of members based on subscription type.  What I'm looking for is a count of officers, enlisted, and civilians (I'm creating a game).  The member table registers actual members, while the subscriptions table registers the type of subscription they have.  Since each subscription is 1-year, this results in multiple subscription records per member.

The output I'm looking for is

```
Enlisted Officer Civilian
5  12  32
```

The problem is the record count.  I tried:
`models.Subscription.objects.values('Subscription_Type').annotate(grouping=Count('Subscription_Type'))`
but if I have a single member with new subscription (say 12/1/2013), then a re-subscription (say 12/1/2014), it shows as a count of two.  I need a count of one, because it's only one member.

I have the following tables:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    member_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    home_phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    cell_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    fax_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    Cell_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_joined = models.DateField()
    invite_reason = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name


class Subscription(models.Model):
    SType = (
        ('C', 'Civilian'),
        ('E', 'Enlisted'),
        ('O', 'Officer'),
    )
    Subscription_Type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SType)
    Lifetime = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    Modified = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Member.first_name + " " + self.Member.last_name + ": " + self.Subscription_Type + "; last modified: " + self.Modified.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have to count only _current_ subscriptions?

Comment: Yes, exactly!!!  Thank you.